# Chrome lighthouse says my manifest isn't finding my html

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

So I wanted to make a pwa that you could download. I followed some tutorial and created the manifest file. But when I open lighthouse it gives me this error:

Web app manifest or service worker do not meet the installability requirements

No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest.

Down here you can see my file managment. What do I have to fix?

thank you

[image]